# table typesetting

Tags: tables, tabularx

Please I need to have a adequate height of cells in this table (exactly the 8th column, this is the code in latex :
[image: current state in latex]

```
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{p{1.25cm} p{0.65cm} p{1.4cm} p{0.40cm}p{0.4cm}p{1.25cm}p{0.65cm} p{0.5cm}p{0.5cm}p{0.5cm} p{0.5cm} p{0.5cm}p{0.5cm}}

\hline \multicolumn{2}{c}{\textbf{Etude}} &  \multicolumn{3}{c}{\textbf{Sol}} &  \multicolumn{6}{c}{\textbf{Colonne}} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{\textbf{Rapport}}\\
\hline \textbf{Auteurs} & \textbf{Année} &  \textbf{Type}  &$D_s$  \footnotesize{$(mm)$} & \textbf{$H_s$}  \footnotesize{$(mm)$}& \textbf{Type}&$D_c$  \footnotesize{$(mm)$} & $L_c$ \footnotesize{$(mm)$}  & $G_{min}$ \footnotesize{$(mm)$} &  $G_{max}$ \footnotesize{$(mm)$}& $\dfrac{D_c}{G_{max}}$ &  $\dfrac{L_c}{D_c}$ & $\dfrac{D_s}{D_c}$ \\
\\ 
\hline \cite{Pivarc2011} & 2011 & \multirow {3}{*}{ Argile sableuse} & 125 & 600 & Gravier & 300 & 5.0  & 2 & 5 & 12 & 60 & 2.08 \\
\cline{8-9} &&&&&&& 420 &&&& 7.0 & \\
\cline{8-9} &&&&&&& 540 &&&& 9.0 &\\
\hline
\end{tabularx}

\end{table}
```

I have the same table with word software like this :
[image: in word]

Comment: Welcome to TeX-SX! As a new member, it is recommended to visit the [Welcome](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) and the [Tour](https://tex.stackexchange.com/tour) pages to be informed about our format and also to know about [Minimal Example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228).

Comment: It might help you to look into the `multirow` package.

Comment: Could you please post a complete code of what you've tried?

Comment: `tabularx` should have at least one column of `X` type!

Comment: To solve your problem we need to know your document's page layout. So, please extend your code snippet to complete small document beginning with `\documentclass` and ending with `\end{document}`. Preamble should contain packages relevant for your table ad page layout definition,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a first attempt to typeset something that may be what you are after. I use `tabular*` as main table, and nested tabular to set the multiline cells. Those nested tabulars are typeset using a new command `\thead` (*modified from an example by Heiko Oberdiek*).

I use `@{\extracolsep{\fill}}` in combination with `\tabcolsep{0pt}` to set space between columns, so the the tabular stretch out to the full line width (*modified from an example by Mico*). In addition, I use the declaration `!{\hspace{18pt}}` to secure a minimum space between the four group of columns.

In this updated answer, I use fixed width columns as in the beginning of the table. To have line break in the `\cite`-cite command, I enclose them in an `\url`-command using the package [xurl](https://ctan.org/pkg/xurl) (defining a new command `\tcite`, and enclose the whole construction in a `\parbox` to ensure line breaks within the cell.

[image]

```
\documentclass[landscape]{article}
\usepackage{array, amsmath, booktabs, caption, xurl}
\usepackage{geometry}
\DeclareUrlCommand\tcite{\urlstyle{rm}} % defining a table cite command which
                                        % enclose the cite-command in an url

% Multi-line left-aligned text with manual line breaks.
% The base line of the whole is at the top row.
\newcommand*{\thead}[1]{%
\multicolumn{1}{l}{\begingroup
    \renewcommand*{\arraystretch}{1}%
    \small\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}#1\end{tabular}%
  \endgroup
}}


\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{0pt}

\caption{Strange table}

\begin{tabular*}{\linewidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}*{2}{wc{40pt}}!{\hspace{18pt}}ccc!{\hspace{18pt}}cccccc!{\hspace{18pt}}*{2}{wc{20pt}}}

\toprule
\multicolumn{2}{c}{\bfseries Etude}     &
\multicolumn{3}{c}{\bfseries Sol}       &
\multicolumn{6}{c}{\bfseries Colonne}   &
\multicolumn{2}{c}{\bfseries Rapport} \\
\cmidrule{1-2}\cmidrule{3-5}\cmidrule{6-11}\cmidrule{12-13}
\bfseries Auteurs                             & 
\bfseries Année                               &
\bfseries Type                                &
\thead{$D_s$\\\footnotesize{(mm)}}            &
\thead{\textbf{$H_s$} \\ \footnotesize{(mm)}} &
\bfseries Type                                &
\thead{$D_c$ \\\footnotesize{(mm)}}           &
\thead{$L_c$ \\\footnotesize{(mm)}}           &
\thead{$G_{min}$\\\footnotesize{(mm)}}        &
\thead{$G_{max}$ \\\footnotesize{(mm)}}       &
$\dfrac{D_c}{G_{max}}$                        &
$\dfrac{L_c}{D_c}$                            &
$\dfrac{D_s}{D_c}$                            \\
\midrule%\cite{Pivarc2011} 
\parbox{40pt}{\raggedright\tcite{\cite{Pivarc2011}}} &  % put the \cite-command
                                                        % inside \tcite (which is an url)
2011                     &
\thead{Argile\\sableuse} &
125                      &
600                      &
Gravier                  &
300                      &
\thead{5.0\\
       \midrule 420\\
       \midrule 540}     & 
2                        & 
5                        & 
12                       & 
\thead{60\\
       \midrule7.0\\
       \midrule9.0}      & 
2.08                    \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular*}

\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, for your willingness to answer my question. I am wondering if there is a way to activate the citation while keeping the width of the cell fixed.

Comment: @A.BOUZIANE I will have a look.

Comment: @A.BOUZIANE The problem here is that `Pivarc2011` is not a word and cannot easily be hyphenated. I manage to have it distributed on several line by loading the package `\url` and enclose the word `Pivarc(2011) a `url`, and the url in a parbox. However, I have not tested it using a real `\cite` command. See the updated example.

Comment: thank you very match for the response, i try with the solution but it doesn't work :( , so i keep the citation as word  (waiting for a proposition)  thanks you . i am asking if you have a book or some site where i can learn more how to write correctly tables  in latex.